# Redirects doesn't work on netlify with nextjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, netlify

I simply followed the doc by adding this to my next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
   async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/",
        destination: "/coming-soon",
        permanent: false,
      },
    ];
  },
}
```

It does work on my machin even when I build the app but on netlify there is no redirect at all for some reason

Comment: You need custom configuration on your netlify instance: https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the official Netlify [docs](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/common-configurations/next-js/#edit-next-config-js):

> **Redirects and rewrites using `next.config.js` aren't currently supported for Next.js sites on Netlify.** If you have these specified in a `next.config.js` file for your project, check out our [redirects and rewrites](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/) docs to learn how to set them up in a `_redirects` or `netlify.toml` file instead.

So you basically need to create a `_redirects` file  at the top level of your project with the following contents:

```sh
/    /coming-soon    302
```

The 302 status code is equivalent to `permanent: false` that you've done in your config.

If you have a `netlify.toml`, then you can add something like this to make your stuff work:

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/"
  to = "/coming-soon"
  status = 302
  force = false
```

References:

- [Redirects and rewrites | Netlify Docs](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/)
- [Redirect options | Netlify Docs](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/redirect-options/)
- [Migrating an existing Next.js project to Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2021/05/04/migrating-an-existing-next.js-project-to-netlify/)

Comment: It's best to use status code 301 as Netlify examples suggest.
If you want to automate the process, I've written a little CLI script: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-to-netlify-redirect-exporter

Answer (score -1):

When we deploy a Next.js project on Netlify it automatically gets all the necessary dependencies including the [Essential Next.js plugin](https://github.com/netlify/netlify-plugin-nextjs#readme) (If it is not installed in the plugin tab, we have to install it manually). This plugin configures your Netlify site to allow essential Next.js capabilities. Version 4 of the Essential Next.js plugin adds support for native Next.js rewrites and redirects.

Basically, you can use native Next.js redirects/rewrites (configured in next.config.js) in Netlify by installing the Essential Next.js plugin version 4 or higher to your Next.js site deployed in Netlify.

Refer this to learn more about using Next.js and Netlify redirects/rewrites rules.

- https://github.com/netlify/netlify-plugin-nextjs/blob/main/docs/redirects-rewrites.md